# Why maven build is failing with error: "package com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver does not exist"?

Tags: java

I have created project want to deploy it using **Jenkins** and **Git**. I created maven project and added all the dependencies required.
My one of class contains following code-

```
try {
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver());
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Problem registering JDBC driver");
}
```

and indicates error at ***com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver()*** this line like not able to find **com.microsoft** package.

I have added maven dependency for Microsoft server driver in POM file-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.0.jre8</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now when i try to run that project with **clean install** it gives error as:

> package com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver does not exist

and fails the build.
What should I do to remove this error and run my project successfully?

Comment: did you update the project?maven->updateproject

Comment: You should **not** load a JDBC driver like that. Calling `DriverManager.registerDriver` is not for applications to be called, it is **only** for JDBC drivers to register themselves when loaded. If you need to load, then use `Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver")` and the driver will register itself.

Answer (score 1):

You include the artifact with `<scope>test</scope>` but apparently use it in the main code.

Change the scope to `compile` or (if scope of this artifact is not managed elsewhere) simply remove `<scope>test</scope>`.

For the future, what helps with this kind of questions is to simply run:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dscope=compile
```

You will see a tree of artifacts considered for the compilation.